# Integrating my compass into another activity

Tags: android

I created a compass in one of the activities in my app and now I want to take that compass and place it into another activity. It should behave as just another view if possible but still retain it's functionality.

Is there a way to embed one activity inside another? Or would it be better to just try to re-create the compass in the activity that it should be placed in?

I would add a screenshot but because it's a compass it's constantly updating which throws the ability of the DDMS to take a screenshot I think. So I'll explain: the compass lines, pointing from North to South and West to East, are painted over the entire activity. Is there anyway to limit this and stop it from happening ?

---

Update - this isn't going well - I can't get the compass to appear at all based on the advice given. So I have included the code I'm using to see if anyone has any ideas?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView( R.layout.new_compass_layout );

    // New instance of our custom drawable view
    mCustomDrawableView = new CustomDrawableView( this );

    // Register the sensor listeners
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    accelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    magnetometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);

    //********************************************
    // Test for adding a new view
    RelativeLayout myLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById( R.id.reltveLayoutCmpss );

    // Add layout parameters
    LayoutParams testLayoutParams = new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
    mCustomDrawableView.setLayoutParams( testLayoutParams );
    mCustomDrawableView.onMeasure( 100, 100 );
    // Add it to the layout
    myLayout.addView( mCustomDrawableView );
    //********************************************

// More code in here - doesn't affect painting

}

 // Drawable for my compass view
public class CustomDrawableView extends View 
{
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure( int widthMeasure, int heightMeasure )
    {
        this.setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasure, heightMeasure);
    }

    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public CustomDrawableView(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);

        paint.setColor(0xff00ff00);
        paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);;
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {
        // Get dimensions of the screen
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
        int centerx = width/2;
        int centery = height/2;


        canvas.drawLine( centerx, 0, centerx, height, paint );
        canvas.drawLine( 0, centery, width, centery, paint);

        if( azimuth != null )
        {
            canvas.rotate( -azimuth * 360/(2*3.14159f), centerx, centery );
            paint.setColor( 0xff0000ff );

            canvas.drawLine( centerx, -1000, centerx, +1000, paint );
            canvas.drawLine( -1000, centery, 1000, centery, paint );

            canvas.drawText( "N - ^", centerx+5, centery-10, paint );
            canvas.drawText( "S - v", centerx-10, centery+15, paint);

            paint.setColor( 0xff00ff00 );
        }
    }
}
```

Can you actually use the onMeasure() and setMeasuredDimension() on a view which uses paint?
Thanks

Comment: Is your compass a View? If not, make it a View so that you can use it in all layouts, regardless of Activty etc.

Comment: I just made it into a view and have added it dynamically - see my update above

Comment: If the lines are painted over the entire activity, check the bounds of your view, properly implement your compass views onMeasure  to limit it's size and make sure you draw your lines according to the size of the View, not the screen.

Comment: It doesn't have an onMeasure() method only a measure method

Comment: All views have a protected void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec). It's protected so you need to override it. 
developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure(int,int)

Comment: What if you make your CustomDrawableView a static class, change your onMeasure to call setMeasuredDimension(100, 100) and add it directly to your layout (reltveLayoutCmpss) in the xml file instead. You need to override the (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) constructor in CustomDrawableView for this as well.

Comment: I like your thinking - i'll try it soon - have been programming all day and my head is fried!

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but I think that if one uses the paint method in android then you can't limit it's size as it's not really a traditional view but rather something which uses the entire canvas (activity) to draw on. I went with reducing the overall size of my compass to make it fit into the space available.

Answer (score 0):

ActivityGroup / Fragment. I never used them yet, don't ask how ;)

Best regards.

Comment: I ll look into this way but I did manage to do I - I had to add all the code in and use the LayoutParams to add it the view dynamically